# Protecting against trapped water between guardrail post and surrounding wood

Tags: deck, waterproofing, railing

I have attached deck guardrail posts in a way shown on page 3 of Simpson Strong Tie's [T-C-GRDRLPST22 bulletin](https://ssttoolbox.widen.net/view/pdf/xeuwdrqaen/T-C-GRDRLPST22.pdf).

[image]

There are couple of places where water could be trapped:

1. Between double blocking or blocking and joists (along the length of blocking).
2. Between guardrail post, rim joist, and blocking butts. Highlighted below.

[image]

For (1) I plan to use wide enough butyl joist tape to prevent water from getting in-between the boards.

I am not sure how to protect against (2). Is there a recommended approach to this?

Comment: What are the posts made from? Are they pressure treated? Cedar?

Comment: Posts are made of cedar. Not pressure treated.

Answer (score 1):

Stain.

Not sure how you're finishing the exposed portion of the post, but, if you stained the bottom portion that will be below the decking that would help prevent any water absorption for quite some time.

Oil and water don't mix, a quality oil based stain could potentially help quite a bit.

Sherwin Williams SuperDeck oil based stain is a great product, I have used it quite a bit in the past.

*Image Credit: Sherwin Williams*
[image: Sherwin Williams SuperDeck stain]

Comment: Yes this! Even the cheapest protective oil, boiled linseed oil. would work.

Answer (score 0):

use joist tape there too but fold it so it goes half-inch up the post.

Comment: "half-inch" or more. You probably don't want it to show, but more is better than less.

Comment: Wouldn't the joist tape detach with time, trapping the water between the joist tape and the post, creating even better conditions for rot? I suspect the glue is not something that will hold up with time very well.

Comment: Thinking more about it, would some sort of pressure strap around the joist tape work to prevent detachment?

Comment: the tape is pretty sticky stuff.

Comment: It is sticky when first applied, indeed. Doesn't it dry out over time, especially at the edge of a vertically applied tape?

Comment: The joist tape has a useful life span. so does the wood. Neither will last forever.  The idea of the tape, or any prevention method is to extend the amount of time that the wood will last before decay becomes an issue.  Yes the tape will degrade.  Water will find it's way into the wood.  What you are hoping for is an extension of time  before the natural occurrences are such that you must take action.  That is all that you will get.

Comment: @RDMan, my suspicion is that both the joist tape and the wood can significantly outlast the glue, but that trapped water will quickly degrade the guardrail post. I do not expect any of the components here to last forever, I am just trying to make sure they will last as long as they could in given conditions.

Comment: @LokiKriasus to ensure this lasts as long as possible, apply tape. That way, you have the lifespan of the wood _plus_ the lifespan of the tape/adhesive. Sure, once the adhesive dries up, it won't do much good anymore, but when that happens (several years from now) is when the clock on the wood inside the post connector starts ticking, as opposed to that clock starting right now.

Comment: @FreeMan, I don't think that's the case - once the tape starts peeling off, it will trap water between the tape and the wood, not letting it dry. I suspect that will rot the wood much faster than if there was no tape at all.